# Unable to create root user using Ansible Database module in MariaDB 10.3 on CentOS 7 host

Tags: ansible, mariadb, centos7, access-denied

I'm writing a simple playbook for the installation of MariaDB 10.3 using Ansible from Ubuntu 18.04 to my virtual machine running on CentOS 7 and I'm getting the following error which I'm unable to fix after even reading tons of solutions on online forums. Any help would be highly appreciated. Here's the error message

```
PLAY [myvm] *************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **************************************************************************************************
ok: [myvm]

TASK [MariaDB_10.3 official repository] *********************************************************************************
ok: [myvm]

TASK [Installation of mariadb and packages] *****************************************************************************
ok: [myvm]

TASK [Starting and enabling the service] ********************************************************************************
ok: [myvm]

TASK [Setting up root credentials] **************************************************************************************
[WARNING]: Module did not set no_log for update_password
fatal: [myvm]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "unable to connect to database, check login_user and login_password are correct or /root/.my.cnf has the credentials. Exception message: (1045, u\"Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)\")"}

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************************************
myvm                       : ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Here's my complete Ansible playbook

````
---

- hosts: myvm 
  become: yes
  vars: 
        mysql_root_password: "somerandom"
        wp_user_pass: "anotherrandom"

  tasks:
      - name: MariaDB_10.3 official repository
        yum_repository:
           name: MariaDB
           description: MariaDB_10.3
           baseurl: http://yum.mariadb.org/10.3/centos7-amd64
           gpgkey: https://yum.mariadb.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-MariaDB
           gpgcheck: yes

      - name: Installation of mariadb and packages
        yum: 
           name: 
              - mariadb-server
              - MySQL-python
           state: present

      - name: Starting and enabling the service
        service:
           name: mariadb
           state: started
           enabled: yes

      - name: Setting up root credentials
        mysql_user:
           name: root
           password: "{{ mysql_root_password }}"
           host: localhost
           login_unix_socket: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
           priv: '*.*:ALL,GRANT'
           check_implicit_admin: true 
           state: present

      - name: Creating a new database for wordpress
        mysql_db:
           name: wp_db
           login_user: wp_user
           login_password: "{{ wp_user_pass }}"
           login_host: localhost
           login_port: 3306
           state: present

      - name: Creating a user for wordpress
        mysql_user:
           name: wp_user
           password: "{{ wp_user_pass }}"
           host: localhost
           priv: 'wp_db.*:ALL'
           state: present

      - name: Removing test database
        mysql_db:
           name: test
           login_user: root
           login_password: "{{ mysql_root_password }}"
           state: absent```
````

Comment: There is an answer on a more dedicated site:https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/102066/ansible-how-to-change-mysql-server-root-password-by-reprovisioning-the-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error message gives a clue:

```
"msg": "unable to connect to database, check login_user and login_password are correct or /root/.my.cnf
```

Try this:

```
- name: Setting up root credentials
  mysql_user:
    name: root
    password: "{{ mysql_root_password }}"
    login_user: root
    login_password: "{{mysql_root_password}}"
    host: localhost
    login_unix_socket: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
    priv: '*.*:ALL,GRANT'
    check_implicit_admin: true 
    state: present
```

The URL below has a few good examples, especially for handling the new expires password feature in v5.7 onward.

Especially this part onwards...

```
- name: Detect and properly set root password
  stat:
    path: /root/.my.cnf
  register: r

- mysql_user:
    name: root
    password: "{{ mysql_root_password }}"
when: r.stat.exists==True

- name: Set new password from temporary password
  shell: 'mysql -e "SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD(''{{ mysql_root_password }}'');" --connect-expired-password -uroot -p"{{ tmp_root_password.stdout }}"'
  when: r.stat.exists==False

# Now that the root password is set to the specified, make it default for the client.
- name: Copy my.cnf
  template:
    src: root_my.cnf.j2
    dest: /root/.my.cnf
    force: yes
```

See full source here: [Handle mysql_secure_installation in Ansible](https://gist.github.com/tiabc/3a899f00df88589d4c674071f19198ea)